Confusing Remark on the Deformation Retraction from $\mathbf{X}$ to $\mathsf{X}?$ - Hatcher's Algebraic Topology
This question has been asked on here by many others; however, an accepted answer has yet to be provided. The statement reads as follows:

(pg. 2, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology) "Not all deformation retractions arise in this simple way from mapping cylinders. For example, the thick $\mathbf{X}$ deformation retracts to the thin $\mathsf{X},$ which in turn deformation retracts to the point of intersection of its two crossbars. The net result is a deformation retraction of $\mathbf{X}$ onto a point, during which certain pairs of points follow paths that merge before reaching their final destination. Later in this section we will describe a considerably more complicated example, the so-called house with two rooms."

My confusion. "Not all deformation retractions arise in this simple way from mapping cylinders." What exactly is Hatcher trying to say here? Is he trying to say that not all deformation retractions will induce a mapping cylinder? At which point, I don't see how the provided example serves as a counter-example. Could one not just embed $\mathbf{X}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with its center at the origin), construct the deformation retraction map $f_t:\mathbf{v}\mapsto (1-t)\mathbf{v},$ and quickly derive a cylinder mapping for $f?$  Or is Hatcher saying something different? The way in which the remainder of the paragraph reads suggests to me that Hatcher is really meaning to say that "There exist deformation retractions which don't directly induce a 'smooth-looking' mapping cylinder", but I'm not sure what significance such a claim would hold. It should be rather obvious that one could easily compose almost any two compatible deformation retractions, and output a non-'smooth-looking' mapping cylinder, no?
I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Note. "[T]his simple way" refers to, for instance, mapping cylinders which are induced by linear homotopy maps (rel$A)$ from space $X$ onto subspace $A.$ (In other words, the "easy" examples.)

I agree that the remark is unclear, but I'm pretty sure that what he's trying to say is something like this: Let $X$ be a space, $Y \subset X$ a subspace and $f_t$ a deformation retraction of $X$ onto $Y$. Then it need not be the case that there is a homeomorphism $\phi\colon X \cong M_g$ for $g$ some map with codomain $Y$ such that $\phi \circ f_t$ is the standard deformation retraction of $M_g$ onto $Y$. In his counterexample, this follows from the fact that in his chosen deformation retractions paths "merge" before $t = 1$, which is not the case for the standard deformation retraction.

Here the emphasis is really on the deformation retraction itself, i.e. on the map $f_t$. As you point out, a deformation retraction from the thick X to a point can easily be realized as a mapping cylinder one,  just not this particular one.

@BenSteffan Got it. Thank you!

As defined about a page before the part you quoted,

A deformation retraction of a space $X$ onto a subspace $A$ is a family of maps $f_t : X \to X$, $t \in I$, such that $f_0 = 1$ (the identity map), $f_1(X)=A$, and $f_t \mid A = 1$ for all $t$.

To be a bit more careful, this family of maps is a continuous function $f : X \times I \to X$, and the individual functions $f_t$ in this family are given by the formula $f_t(x)=f(x,t)$.
So, what Hatcher is saying is this: every mapping cylinder structure induces an associated deformation retraction; but it is not true that every deformation retraction is the one that is induced by a mapping cylinder structure.
Your "It should be obvious..." comment is right on point, and in fact Hatcher's example regarding the "thick $X$" is an example just like you mention: a composition of two deformation retractions which is not associated to a mapping cylinder structure. As you rightly observe, you can replace that "composed" deformation retraction with a different deformation retraction of the thick $X$, one that is indeed associated to a mapping cylinder structure.
But what's particularly interesting is that there are in fact examples of spaces $X$ and subspaces $A$ such that a deformation retraction from $X$ to $A$ exists, and yet there does not exist any mapping cylinder structure which induces a deformation retraction from $X$ to $A$. For a very simple example, take $X$ to be a $Y$ shape and take $A$ to be any point of the $Y$ except for the point where the three branches of the $Y$ join. To prove that this has no mapping cylinder structure, it suffices to observe two things. First, if $Y$ were a mapping cylinder from some topological space $Z$ to the space $A$, then the $Y-A$ would homeomorphic to $Z \times [0,1)$; each component of $Y-A$ would therefore be homeomorphic to the Cartesian product with $[0,1)$ of some topological space (namely some component of $Z$). However, the component of $Y-A$ containing the branch point of the $Y$ is not homeomorphic to the product with $[0,1)$ of any topological space.
As for the significance of Hatcher's comment, his intent is to warn the reader not to make an unwarranted assumption about general deformation retractions. It seems you did not need this warning! But, other readers might need it.

Perfect! That's everything I needed. Thanks again.

Hello again. I'm trying to understand why none of the deformation retractions from $Y$ to a single, non-center point induce a mapping cylinder. Is there a theorem or statement which could point me in the right direction as to why this is? (If this is too much, then please do not feel obligated to answer. I can keep searching on my own.)

I added a bit to that paragraph to explain this issue.

Dear Lee, I am re-reading the response you have given (specifically the part about how $Y$-shaped space cannot DR to a single point which is not the intersection of the three branches), but I'm a little lost on a few things: (i) "To prove that this has no mapper cylinder structure"... Do you mean "no mapping cylinder with structure which induces DR"? (ii) "component of $Y-A$ containing the branch point of the $Y$"... Is "the $Y$" referencing the space $Y$ or the $Y$-shaped space? And is the "branch point" referring to the point of intersection of all branches of $X$? Or something else? Thanks!

The "$Y$ shaped space", also known as the "$Y$" to save characters, is formally a $1$-dimensional simplicial complex consising of three $1$-simplices which share a single common endpoint that I'll denote $p$, and which have no other points in common. $A$ is any single point of $Y-{p}$. The space $Y$ does deformation retract to $A$. There does not exist any mapping cylinder structure on $Y$ which induces a deformation retraction to $A$.

So just to make sure, you are saying that there exists no mapping cylinders at all? Or that there exist no mapping cylinders which will induce DR? The way your original answer is phrased seems to show that you are proving the former (which would thereby imply the latter). And I understand that this is not to say there will exist no DR, but only that there exist no DR which may be induced by a mapping cylinder.

No, I am not saying that there exist no mapping cylinder structures at all on $Y$. You seem not to have noticed that $A$ is a point of $Y-{p}$. To put this in words, $A$ is a point of $Y$ that is not equal to the point $p$. And for that choice of $A$, I am saying that there does not exist a mapping cylinder structure on $Y$ that induces a deformation retraction from $Y$ to $A$.  But there does exist a mapping cylinder structure on $Y$ which induces a deformation retraction from $Y$ to $p$.

I see. Thanks again.
